# Вывод дохода от AdMob в Беларуси для физ. лица

Tags: google-play, admob, android

Здравствуйте.

Скажите, пожалуйста, может, у кого-то есть опыт вывода дохода от AdMob в Беларуси для физ. лица. Знаю, были похожие вопросы, но, насколько я понял, у наc в Беларуси все немного сложнее.

Answer (score 1):

Похоже тут есть ответ для Adsence, a т.к. AdMob тоже самое, то можно попробовать по этой схеме
http://s13.by/2007/09/19/kak-obnalichit-cheki-adsense-v-belarusi/